# Running clojure as JAVA file

Tags: java, jar, clojure, jvm

Is it possible to build a JAR file from a clojure file using the `jar cf jar-file input-file(s)` command, and then running it on another machine (without clojure) like with java file command?

What is the best way to execute a clojure program on another computer which has access to java but not to clojure?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely!

The easiest way to do this is to use [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) to manage your project. Once you have a [project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/sample.project.clj) set up, it's as simple as calling:

```
lein uberjar
```

to generate a portable .jar file.

Comment: so the steps would be: `lein new my-file` cd to the directory, `lein uberjar` and then i could send the `project.clj` file for example per email to some one, he runs `java project.clj`? Am i right?

Comment: No, project.clj manages things like version, dependencies, etc. Lein requires it, and lein uberjar generates a jar file that you could send to someone and run with java.

Comment: well i am getting an error, i cant see what am i doing false: i created the new project called test (lein new test), then ran lein uberjar from inside  the test directory, which creates two jar files inside the target dir : `test-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `test-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar`. then i run from inside the target directory `java test-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and it says:  Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class test-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: In your project.clj, you need to specify a key/value pair :main somenamespace. It will look in that namespace for a -main function.

Comment: what should this namespace then be? The same ns as in the src/file-name/core.clj ?

Comment: If you want to run a program by itself instead of importing it as a library, you need to have a main function which will get executed. With Lein, you specify that there is a main function (and it's not just a library to be imported) with the :main key, and the value is the namespace where you implement -main. If you used the namespace you mention, then it will expect that you defined a -main function within that namespace. You can add a (defn -main [] (some code)) there and point lein to that namespace and it will get executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90359/discussion-between-amir-teymuri-and-jwde).

Answer (score 1):

In your core.clj you need to add gen-class in your ns macro like this:

```
(ns test.core
   ...........
   (:gen-class))
```

next run `lein uberjar`
next run from your project root folder

```
java -jar target/test...standalone.jar
```

Comment: i did this, it starts up the REPL! Is the project root folder the test folder created as i runned `lein new test`? This is how you run clojure programs as java executable? Does it have to do with maybe some version differences of lein or something like that? By the way this is my test/src/test/core.clj: `(ns test.core
(:gen-class))

(defn foo
  "I don't do a whole lot."
  [x]
  (println x "Hello, World!"))`

Comment: It worked for me. I just uploaded a demo project here https://github.com/bit-twit/konstantinopol . Can you check that out ? Just check core.clj and project.clj see if it makes any difference

Comment: Yup, the folder created by lein new test. You should see the  project.clj file in the root folder.

Comment: If I do `lein version` I get `Leiningen 2.5.1 on Java 1.8.0_45 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM` , what do you get ?

Comment: i get: `Leiningen 2.5.1 on Java 1.7.0_79 OpenJDK Server VM`

Comment: the differences from your project.clj are: i didnt have the :main namespace.core in it. from your core.clj: i didnt have any -main function in it. I added these, and then ran `java -jar target/test-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar` from inside the test folder, i got this: `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
nil`. I also added the `(:gen-class)` to the core.clj: `(ns test.core
(:gen-class))`

Comment: That `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar`  might cause problems. Try setting the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS variable to  nothing before  running the jar , like this  : `set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=` (Windows) or `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=` (Linux)